# How can I write $(a, \infty)$ as the infinite union of half open intervals?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the following expression correct?

$(a, \infty) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (a, \infty-\dfrac{1}{n})$?

Edit:
The above expression should be: 
$(a, \infty) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (a, \infty-\frac{1}{n}]$?  "

And my original question should've been:

"How can I write $(a, \infty)$ as the infinite union of **left half-open intervals**?"

It is insufficient to merely state "half open intervals", because one can have right half-open or left half-open intervals, which have the form [a,b) and (a,b] respectively.

**The correction: 
$(a, \infty) = \displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (a, n+1] $**

Thank you.

Comment: What does $\infty - \frac 1n$ mean?

Comment: sorry I meant union!

Comment: In addition to the problem noted by @Bye_World, your intervals are not half-open.

Comment: my apologies! I meant \bigcup

Comment: @ckc62: You’ve fixed the typo, but the substantive problems remain: $\infty-\frac1n$ isn’t meaningful, and even if it were, your intervals are not half-open.

Comment: to be more specific, I am trying to prove whether or not $(a, \infty)$ is open in the upper limit topology, which amounts to showing if I can write it as an infinite union of half open intervals in the form (a, b]

Comment: $(a,\infty)=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty(a+n,a+n+1]$ is a union of half-open intervals.

Comment: Hint: $a+n$ grows without bound.

Comment: Ah, that's right. Thank you!

Comment: When writing up a question like this, please be as specific as possible. The original question says just "half-open intervals," which could be open on either end. You can write $(a,\infty)$ as a union of _two_ such intervals. But you actually _meant_ to ask about intervals open only on the bottom. Can you see how that detail makes a huge difference in the answer to the question?

Comment: @DavidK Thank you for pointing that out to me. I am still learning to be precise in my language. I appreciate you clarifying how it should've been written.

Comment: Now that you know how your question should've been written, why don't you use the edit button to improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, $\infty-\frac{1}{n}$ does not have a clear meaning.

So here is my hint: What about intervals of the form $(a,n]$? What $n$'s should we consider? Can you see the suitable union of intervals?

I hope that helps!

Comment: The author changed the question after I posted my answer. I made an edit now. Thank you.